# Google Chrome loading extensions that I didn't install

Tags: javascript, security, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have Google Chrome Version 38.0.2125.111 m installed on my windows XP machine.
Whenever I start Chrome, it loads Google Now and Google+ Hangouts extensions automatically (see attached screenshot of task manager).

[image]

Although they automatically stop after a minute, its troubling me because I never installed either of these extensions.

1. What is Google doing with loading these extensions without me explicitly installing them?
2. Can I block them from loading?

Comment: Those who vote to close probably don't view this as a programming question. And that's true, this question would be more suitable at Superuser.com. I'm not actively following questions over there though, so if you posted over there, I wouldn't have read and answered your question; nevertheless you should still have posted the question over there, there might be someone else who would have known the answer. If not, then don't cross-post to Stack Overflow, but mail me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. These are component extensions, extensions that are bundled with Chrome.
2. If you don't use any of these services, you can disable them by starting Chrome with the `--disable-component-extensions-with-background-pages` flag.

Comment: Will it block all extensions of just the one injected by Google?

Comment: @KhurramMajeed The ones "injected by Google".